# Rewriting form urls with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, url, redirect

Search forms go to ugly urls normally. If I want users to see nice urls I need to rewrite them on server side and http redirect them.

I'd like to avoid this round trip and rewrite this urls by some simple javascript code.
(without javascript on you'll get the usual http redirect)

What's the most reliable way to do that?

Comment: Why are you so concerned about how your search URLs look? Unlike static pages, which should have friendly permalinks, search results are generally the result of the user filling out the search form and not typing in the URL manually.

Comment: The same pages can be reached by user using search form, and by various static links. I'm trying to make these compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="http://host/target" method="get">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="query" value="..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Would give `http://host/target?query=...`

With plain JS, you could add a listener to the `onSubmit` event (untested):

```
<form action="http://host/target" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.href=this.action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.elements['query'].value); return false;">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="query" value="..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Would give `http://host/target/...`

Comment: Escaping the value appended to the URI is imperative.

Answer (score 4):

If, for example, your ugly URI takes the form of

```
/search.php?query=[input]
```

and your nice URI takes the form of

```
/search/[input]
```

Keep the round-trip implementation (with PHP redirects and URL rewriting) in case the client does not have JavaScript. For those who do, intercept the `submit` event of the form in question (using the event object's `preventDefault` method), and in your event handler, do something like

```
location = '/search/' + encodeURIComponent(queryInputObject.value);
```